# Remove duplicate object elements From arraylist

Tags: java

I have an arraylist called studentList which has some duplicate student elements inside the list. How can I remove duplicate elements?

```
studentList: 
Student{id=S101312, name='Alex Mike', birthdate=10/13/1998}
Student{id=S102732, name='Mark Duong', birthdate=8/28/2001}
Student{id=S103723, name='Hai Hoang Vu', birthdate=4/25/2000}
Student{id=S101312, name='Alex Mike', birthdate=10/13/1998}
```

Comment: If order doesn't matter, you can put them in a `Set`

Comment: @Kidus I tried to put into set but it still contains duplicated afterwards

Comment: Did you override `hashCode()`?

Comment: @Kidus I dont think so... Can you help me with that

Comment: In your `Student` class override `hashCode()` to return `Object.hash(id, name, birthdate)`

Comment: You need to override hashCode *and* equals to have a Set correctly detect duplicates.

Comment: What defines a duplicate? All the member fields? Just the `id` field?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Student` class override `hashCode()` and `equals()` like so

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Student student = (Student) o;
    return id == student.id && Objects.equals(name, student.name) && Objects.equals(birthdate, student.birthdate);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Object.hash(id, name, birthdate);
}
```

Then convert to `Set`

```
Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>(studentList);
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt remove duplicate. It only arranges the order

Comment: @darkeNxd Show the definition of your `Student` class

Answer (score 1):

**Way One:**

You can use Stream distinct method, (**Easy and Faster way**):

```
List<Student> uniqueStudentList = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Way Two:**

```
// Duplicate Object  List
java.util.List<Student> duplicateStudentList = new ArrayList<>();



// Unique Object  List
HashSet<Student> uniqueStudentList = new HashSet(studentList); 


// Class with Override **equals** and **hashCode** Method : 

public class Student {

    private String id; 
    private String name;
    private String birthdate;
    
    
    public Student (String id, String name, String birthdate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }
    
    // Getter and Setter
    
    
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Student) {
            return ((Student) obj).id == ;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String hashCode() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Convert List to Hashset you are adding extra space ,Space complexity of any algorithm takes into account the size of the input. It is a measure of the maximum working memory that will be needed during the execution of the algorithm.
copy List to hashset really bad implementation i.e. it uses constant amount of space as it iterates 
over the list and we know that k < n, so input size will always be the dominating factor in space complexity. So overall the space complexity will be O(n).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Make a `Set` of your `List`.

```
Set < Student > studentsDistinct = Set.copyOf( students ) ;
```

## `record`

Define your class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) in Java 16 and later. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
public record Student ( String id , String name , LocalDate birthDate ) {}
```

The `equals` method, and possibly `hashCode` method, are needed for comparing objects and detecting duplicates.

### `class`

If using a conventional class rather than a record, you will need to write your own overriding implementations of these two methods. Search Stack Overflow to learn more; this has been covered *many* times already.

```java
final class Student
{
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final LocalDate birthDate;

    Student ( String id , String name , LocalDate birthDate )
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String id ( ) { return id; }

    public String name ( ) { return name; }

    public LocalDate birthDate ( ) { return birthDate; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj )
    {
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass() ) return false;
        var that = ( Student ) obj;
        return Objects.equals( this.id , that.id ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.name , that.name ) &&
                Objects.equals( this.birthDate , that.birthDate );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( id , name , birthDate );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Student[" +
                "id=" + id + ", " +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "birthDate=" + birthDate + ']';
    }
}
```

## `List`

Make your list.

```java
List<Student> students = List.of(
    new Student ( "S101312" , "Alex Mike" , LocalDate.of( 1998, 10 , 13 ) , 
    new Student ( "S102732" , "Mark Duong" , LocalDate.of( 2001, 8 , 28 ) , 
    new Student ( "S103723" , "Hai Hoang Vu" , LocalDate.of( 2000, 4 , 25 ) , 
    new Student ( "S101312" , "Alex Mike" , LocalDate.of( 1998, 10 , 13 ) 
);
```

## `Set`

To eliminate duplicates, make a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html). A set by definition permits no duplicates.

```java
Set < Student > studentsDistinct = Set.copyOf( students ) ;
```

## Example code

Put that code together.

```java
record Student(String id , String name , LocalDate birthDate)
{
}

List < Student > students = List.of(
        new Student( "S101312" , "Alex Mike" , LocalDate.of( 1998 , 10 , 13 ) ) ,
        new Student( "S102732" , "Mark Duong" , LocalDate.of( 2001 , 8 , 28 ) ) ,
        new Student( "S103723" , "Hai Hoang Vu" , LocalDate.of( 2000 , 4 , 25 ) ) ,
        new Student( "S101312" , "Alex Mike" , LocalDate.of( 1998 , 10 , 13 ) )
);

Set < Student > studentsDistinct = Set.copyOf( students );

System.out.println( "students = " + students );
System.out.println( "studentsDistinct = " + studentsDistinct );
```

When run.

```
students = [Student[id=S101312, name=Alex Mike, birthDate=1998-10-13], Student[id=S102732, name=Mark Duong, birthDate=2001-08-28], Student[id=S103723, name=Hai Hoang Vu, birthDate=2000-04-25], Student[id=S101312, name=Alex Mike, birthDate=1998-10-13]]
studentsDistinct = [Student[id=S103723, name=Hai Hoang Vu, birthDate=2000-04-25], Student[id=S101312, name=Alex Mike, birthDate=1998-10-13], Student[id=S102732, name=Mark Duong, birthDate=2001-08-28]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import java.util.List;
            import java.util.stream.Collectors;
                /**
                 * 
                 * @author Vaquar khan
                 *
                */
            public class RemoveDuplicateList {
                /**
                 * Student{id=﻿S101312, name='Alex Mike', birthdate=10/13/1998}
                 * Student{id=S102732, name='Mark Duong', birthdate=8/28/2001}
                 * Student{id=S103723, name='Hai Hoang Vu', birthdate=4/25/2000}
                 * Student{id=S101312, name='Alex Mike', birthdate=10/13/1998}
                 * 
                 * @param args
                 */
                public static void main(String[] args) {

                    List<Student> list = new ArrayList();
                    
                    Student student = new Student();
                    student.setId(1);
                    student.setName("Alex Mike");
                    student.setBirthdate("10/13/1998");
                    list.add(student);

                    Student student1 = new Student();
                    student1.setId(1);
                    student1.setName("Alex Mike");
                    student1.setBirthdate("10/13/1998");

                    list.add(student1);
                    
                    Student student2 = new Student();
                    student2.setId(2);
                    student2.setName("Mark Duong");
                    student2.setBirthdate("8/28/2001");

                    list.add(student2);
                    
                    System.out.println("duplicate ="+list.toString());
                    
                    List<RemoveDuplicateList.Student> listWithoutDuplicates = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
                    
                    System.out.println("withoutduplicate ="+listWithoutDuplicates.toString());


                }

                static class Student {
                    private int id;
                    private String name;
                    private String birthdate;

                    public int getId() {
                        return id;
                    }

                    public void setId(int id) {
                        this.id = id;
                    }

                    public String getName() {
                        return name;
                    }

                    public void setName(String name) {
                        this.name = name;
                    }

                    public String getBirthdate() {
                        return birthdate;
                    }

                    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) {
                        this.birthdate = birthdate;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int hashCode() {
                        final int prime = 31;
                        int result = 1;
                        result = prime * result + ((birthdate == null) ? 0 : birthdate.hashCode());
                        result = prime * result + id;
                        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
                        return result;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                        if (this == obj)
                            return true;
                        if (obj == null)
                            return false;
                        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                            return false;
                        Student other = (Student) obj;
                        if (birthdate == null) {
                            if (other.birthdate != null)
                                return false;
                        } else if (!birthdate.equals(other.birthdate))
                            return false;
                        if (id != other.id)
                            return false;
                        if (name == null) {
                            if (other.name != null)
                                return false;
                        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                            return false;
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String toString() {
                        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", birthdate=" + birthdate + "]";
                    }

                }
            }
```